# How to setup log-driver gcplogs while using gcloud compute instance update-container or force it to use default driver?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-stackdriver

**Question**

How to send logs from docker container standard output, to GCP Stackdriver, if this container was deployed using

```
gcloud compute instances update-container
```

command?

**Most recent finding**

```
gcloud compute instances update-container VM_INSTANCE --container-image IMG
```

- **Spins off a container that doesn't respect default log-driver (set in /etc/docker/daemon.json)**
- **gcloud .. update-container uses "docker run" on VM_INSTANCE and allows to provide ARGS and COMMAND to "docker run" but no OPTIONS where I could put --log-driver=gcplogs**

**Context**

My metadata "user-data" section:

```
#cloud-config
write_files:
  - path: /etc/docker/daemon.json
    content: '{"log-driver":"gcplogs"}'

runcmd:
  - systemctl restart docker
```

Gives a proper daemon.json file:

```
p**a@f**i ~ $ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{"log-driver":"gcplogs"}p**a@f**i ~ $
```

I have one container deployed with gcloud update-container command:

```
p**a@f**i ~ $ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
425be3c47e2d        eu.gcr.io/a**i/f**e:9fa641db8491def826eef4f8f288ddbd62f2be1b   "yarn start --enviro…"   6 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            klt--xuyd
```

Double check that config was applied:

```
sudo journalctl -u docker.service
```

```
Apr 26 23:51:10 f**i systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Apr 26 23:51:10 f**i dockerd[1464]: time="2019-04-26T23:51:10.036117615Z" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
Apr 26 23:30:21 f**i dockerd[711]: time="2019-04-26T23:30:21.903908969Z" level=debug msg="Using default logging driver gcplogs"
```

Then when I try to check what is the logger type it's still json-file:

```
p**a@f**i ~ $ docker inspect -f '{{.HostConfig.LogConfig.Type}}' klt--xuyd
json-file
```

Logs in stackdriver are missing. My filter value is:

```
resource.type="gce_instance"
```

All I can see are logs related with Compute Engine starting and stoping instance.

If I stop a docker container and run it with

```
docker run -d --log-driver=gcplogs --log-opt gcp-log-cmd=true IMG
```

Then checking of logger type gives a result:

```
docker inspect -f '{{.HostConfig.LogConfig.Type}}' klt--xuyd
```

```
gcplogs
```

And logs are visible in GCP Stackdriver.

But I can not execute docker run... as this VM is part of my CI/CD environment. Container is updated with

```
gcloud compute instances update-container ${VM_INSTANCE_NAME} --container-image IMG
```

container_vm: cos-stable-74-11895-86-0

I expect logs to be visible without necessity of stoping and starting container since it's set as a default.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/docker-gcplogs-driver) that can help you to configure Google Cloud logging driver on COS images.

Seems that installing the Stackdriver Agent is not an option on COS images as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/#supported_operating_systems).

However, seems that you need to follow the configuration indicated in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/docker-gcplogs-driver#persisting_configuration_across_reboots) to make the configurations persistent across reboots.

Comment: Hi Raul. Thanks for putting your interest in my issue. 1) I've been through this tutorial (https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/docker-gcplogs-driver) but unfortunately it talks about docker run command which is used by update-container command and I cannot access OPTIONS part of docker run with it. 2) Second link you provided is missing some parts making it not working at all. Could you please correct it? Thanks. Pawel

Comment: Hi Pawel, I have corrected the link. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the configurations right. However, as documented in Step 5 of **Writing metadata from the Cloud Platform Console** on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/docker-gcplogs-driver#persisting_configuration_across_reboots), you need to reboot the instance of the VM for the changes to take effect. I believe that is the only thing you are missing as it was not stated in your question that you rebooted it.